# Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?

Tags: rust

I have a very simple example of Rust code which fails to compile:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::base64;

fn main() {
    let auth = format!("{}:{}", "user", "password");
    let auth_b64 = auth.as_bytes().to_base64(base64::MIME);
    println!("Authorization string: {}", auth_b64);
}
```

The compiler error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_base64` found for type `&[u8]` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:36
  |
6 |     let auth_b64 = auth.as_bytes().to_base64(base64::MIME);
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
  = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
          candidate #1: `use rustc_serialize::base64::ToBase64;`
```

It works if I import the trait explicitly:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::base64::{self, ToBase64};

fn main() {
    let auth = format!("{}:{}", "user", "password");
    let auth_b64 = auth.as_bytes().to_base64(base64::MIME);
    println!("Authorization string: {}", auth_b64);
}
```

Why do I need to `use rustc_serialize::base64::ToBase64;`?

Comment: Note that starting from Rust 1.33, if you don't need to refer the trait using its name, you can import it like `use Trait as _;`. This helps with name collisions.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That’s simply the way it is. In Rust a trait must be in scope for you to be able to call its methods.

As for *why*, the possibility of collisions is the reason why. All the formatting traits in `std::fmt` (`Display`, `Debug`, `LowerHex`, &c.) have the same method signature for `fmt`. For example; what would `object.fmt(&mut writer, &mut formatter)` do, for example? Rust’s answer is “you must explicitly indicate by having the trait in scope where the method is.”

Note also how the error message says that “no method named `m` found for type `T` *in the current scope*”.

Note that you don't *have* to import it if you want to use the trait method as a function instead of a method:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::base64;

fn main() {
    let auth = format!("{}:{}", "user", "password");
    let auth_b64 = rustc_serialize::base64::ToBase64::to_base64(auth.as_bytes(), base64::MIME);
    //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    println!("Authorization string: {}", auth_b64);
}
```

Comment: Does this also allow the compiler to leave the remaining methods out of the release, hence creating more compact programs?

Comment: @Jackalope: if a trait is only used through static dispatch (generics) then only the code that is used will be compiled in. If you use dynamic dispatch (trait objects) then all trait methods will be compiled in. (Theoretically it could determine that only certain methods are used and thus evict unused methods from the vtable, but I don’t believe such an optimisation is employed.)

Comment: Why can't the compiler recommend WHAT to bring into the current scope?

Comment: @Jim It does: `= note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a \`use\` for it: candidate #1: \`use rustc_serialize::base64::ToBase64;\``