# Do I have to 'use' a trait in order to call methods defined in that trait?

Tags: rust

I'm  toying with the [cgmath](https://github.com/bjz/cgmath-rs) library. I have the following main.rs file:

```
extern crate cgmath;

use cgmath::vector::{Vector3, EuclideanVector};

fn main() {
    let mypoint = Vector3 { x: 1f64, y: 1f64, z: 3f64 };

    println!("The length of the vector is {}, and the length squared is {}", mypoint.length(), mypoint.length2());
}
```

In my use line, when I omit `EuclideanVector`, I am given the following compilation error:

```
type 'cgmath::vector::Vector3<f64>' does not implement any method in scope named 'length'
```

It appears that the Rust compiler cannot find the `length()` method unless I import one of the traits that `Vector3` uses. Delving into the [source code](https://github.com/bjz/cgmath-rs/blob/master/src/vector.rs#L466), it looks like the length method is defined within the `EuclideanVector` trait.

Intuitively, I should not need to import an trait to use a type that inherits said trait. Is there a technique to do so that I am missing? Is this a nuance specific to the cgmath library? Is this an idiomatic part of Rust that I should become accustomed to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to import a trait to use its impl for a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-its-impl-for-a-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking of traits in terms of inheritance. It might make more sense if you think of a trait as a module that's overloadable with respect to the `Self` type. From this perspective, it makes sense that the trait has to be in scope in order for the compiler to know about its methods, just as a module has to be in scope in order to use it. A particular implication of this is that implementations can be declared alongside the trait they implement rather than the type they implement it for. In this situation, clearly if your code doesn't know about the trait, it can't use its methods.

Another motivation for the current behaviour is that multiple traits can define methods with the same name, and when you have such a conflict for traits implemented for the same type, you can no longer use method call syntax to access their methods. Instead, you have to use function call syntax in order to specify which trait the method is a member of (the trait acting as the module the method is in). If method call syntax used all traits in your program rather than just the ones in scope for method resolution, you'd end up with these conflicts much more often, since you'd have name conflicts with methods in traits that your code isn't actually using directly.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you don't *have* to use `use`. Alternatively:

```
(&mypoint as &cgmath::vector::EuclideanVector).length2()
```

Comment: This is actually a cast and works only if the right-hand side of the `as` can be made into an object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how Rust works. You must always import a trait before you can use its methods. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to import, you can call `cgmath::vector::EuclideanVector::length(&mypoint)`.

(I don't know if this was possible when the question was asked.)