# Implementing a trait does not work when splitting code into files

Tags: rust

I have a simple Rust problem that arises when modularizing the code.

The following works:

```rust
pub trait B {
    fn bar(&self) -> int;
}

pub struct A {
    foo: int
}

impl B for A {
    fn bar(&self) -> int { 5 }
}

// Later...
let a = A { foo: 5 };
println!("{}", a.bar());
```

It prints `5`, but as soon as I modularize the code:

```rust
// lib.rs
mod a;
mod b;

// b.rs
pub trait B {
    fn bar(&self) -> int;
}

// a.rs
use b::B;

pub struct A {
    foo: int
}

impl B for A {
    fn bar(&self) -> int { 5 }
}

// Anywhere:
let test = a::A { foo: 5 };
println!("{}", test.bar());
```

I get a compilation error:

> error: type `a::A` does not implement any method in scope named `bar`

I'm slightly puzzled.

I'm using: `rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (0bdac78da 2014-09-01 21:31:00 +0000)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trait `B` must be in scope whenever you want to call its methods on an object implementing it. You likely forgot to import `B` into the file where you use `A`:

```
// At the top:
use b::B;

// Anywhere:
let test = a::A { foo: 5 };
println!("{}", test.bar());
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-its-impl-for-a-type) answer explains why that's needed.

Comment: You're right! Damn that took some time to figure out.

Comment: Just one more question. What would you do if you need to call the method on two different traits in the same file? Can you somehow import it in a smaller scope inside a function?

Comment: I haven't thought that it would be possible, but I've just tried it and it appears that you can import traits locally in a function (and probably other places as well): [playpen link](http://is.gd/21ItrM).