# Why does using an external crate's function require bringing the dependent trait into scope?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Consider the following code in the [official tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html)

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
}
```

The line `rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101)` is a bit confusing for me since I expect calling `rand::thread_rng()` to automatically resolve the dependency for the trait it is using.

However I need `use rand::Rng;` for it to work.

So does this mean that I have to resolve the dependency manually when I want to use some function in 3rd party crate?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does using an external crate's function require bringing the dependent trait into scope?

**It doesn't**. This compiles just fine:

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng();
}
```

You are then trying to call a method from a trait on the return value of that function call. **That** requires the trait to be in scope, as described in [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273816/155423)