# I can't have every trait and impl in the same file; how to place in seperate file?

Tags: module, rust, access-modifiers

I have a struct, a trait, and impl in the top level file.

```
struct Model {}

trait TsProperties {
    fn create_ar_x_matrix(&self);
}

impl TsProperties for Model {
    fn create_ar_x_matrix(&self){}
}
```

I want to move the trait and impl to a separate file called `test.rs`.  In the main file I have:

```
mod test
```

In test I have:

```
use crate::Model;
```

When I instantiate the struct, Intellisense does not pick up `create_ar_x_matrix`. If the code is in `main.rs` it does.

How do I resolve this?

If I add `pub` I get this error:

```
25 | pub impl TsProperties for Model {                                                                                                                        
   | ^^^ `pub` not permitted here because it's implied
```

if I use `pub` on the struct in main file and put the trait in a separate file:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `create_ar_x_matrix` found for type `Model` in the current scope                                                                         
   --> src/main.rs:353:12                                                                                                                                                   
    |                                                                                                                                                                       
64  | pub struct Model {                                                                                                                                               
    | --------------------- method `create_ar_x_matrix` not found for this
```

Comment: use pub before struct and trait, not impl

Comment: *intellisense does not pick up create_ar_x_matrix* -- Is this just an IDE issue, or do you get an actual compile error?

Comment: See updated....still not working

Comment: make your trait pub and include  `use crate::TsProperties;` too

Comment: Could you paste the *exact* contents of `main.rs` and `test.rs`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the trait.

In `test.rs`:

```
use crate::Model;

pub trait TsProperties {
    fn create_ar_x_matrix(&self);
}

impl TsProperties for Model {
    fn create_ar_x_matrix(&self){}
}
```

In `main.rs`:

```
mod test;
use self::test::TsProperties;

struct Model {}

fn main() {
    let model = Model {};
    model.create_ar_x_matrix();
}
```

Note that `Model` doesn't need to be public, but the trait does. That's because anything in a parent module is automatically visible in child modules.

Comment: [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273816/155423).