# and_then method not found in futures 0.3

Tags: rust, future

After upgrading to futures 0.3, I have this error:

```
no method named `and_then` found for type `impl exchanges::kraken::failure::core::future::future::Future` in the current scope
```

After much debugging, I cannot seem to figure out what is going on.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you [search the crate docs for `and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/?search=and_then), you'll see that it's a method on [`TryFutureExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/trait.TryFutureExt.html#method.and_then) and [`TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.and_then). You must import a trait to have access to its methods.

See also:

- [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273816/155423)