# Why is `thread_rng()` called on `rand` and not `Rng`, like how `stdin()` called on `io`?

Tags: rust

I am at [Generating a Random Number](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#generating-a-random-number) in *The Rust Programming Language*, but I am having trouble understanding the use of the library we add with the keyword `use`:

```rust
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

We are loading two libraries, one we use with the code:

```rust
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

and the other one we use with the code:

```
rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
```

Why is the function `stdin()` called with the keyword `io` when the `thread_rng()` function is called with the keyword `rand` and not the keyword `Rng`?

The book says that we can call `stdin()` with `std::io::stdin` if we didn't load the library, but I can't use `thread_rng()` from `rand::Rng` since the function is in `rand`.

The book says that `Rng` is a trait to define methods, but I do not understand what it does and the difference between the `io` of `std::io` and the `Rng` of `rand::Rng`. Is `io` also a trait?

Comment: You need `use rand::Rng` to call `.gen_range()`, not to call `rand::thread_rng()`.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25273816/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @trentcl Ho yeah, exact. It explain everything, thanks.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the link, it helped. How do I mark the question as Answered ?

Comment: @LucasLam there should be a "close" link under your question post. Click that, then something marked as "duplicate", and paste in the link. Let me know if it doesn't work, and I can do it too.

Comment: @Shepmaster I am sorry, I do not see any "close" link. Under the post there is Share, Edit, Rollback, Delete, Flag. I used Ctrl-f to look for "close", but it didn't show anything related to a link named close. I have a big button 'Answer Your Question' but doesn't seems to be what you are talking about.

Comment: @LucasLam thanks for looking! It may be something that only appears for higher reputation. I've closed it in the meantime.