# Embedded Rust Discovery Book example fails to compile

Tags: rust, embedded

I am new to rust and embedded systems. I was reading and going along "[The Discovery Book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/)" and I can't seem to figure out the errors below.

I have placed this in my `main.rs`:

```rust
#![deny(unsafe_code)]
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

use aux5::{entry, prelude::*, Delay, Leds};

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let (mut delay, mut leds): (Delay, Leds) = aux5::init();

    let half_period = 500_u16;

    loop {
        leds[0].on();
        delay.delay_ms(half_period);

        leds[0].off();
        delay.delay_ms(half_period);
    }
}
```

My auxiliary `lib.rs` contains:

```rust
pub use stm32f3_discovery::{leds::Leds, stm32f3xx_hal, switch_hal};
pub use switch_hal::{ActiveHigh, OutputSwitch, Switch, ToggleableOutputSwitch};

use stm32f3xx_hal::prelude::*;
pub use stm32f3xx_hal::{
    delay::Delay,
    gpio::{gpioe, Output, PushPull},
    hal::blocking::delay::DelayMs,
    stm32,
};

pub type LedArray = [Switch<gpioe::PEx<Output<PushPull>>, ActiveHigh>; 8];

pub fn init() -> (Delay, LedArray) {
    let device_periphs = stm32::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut reset_and_clock_control = device_periphs.RCC.constrain();

    let core_periphs = cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut flash = device_periphs.FLASH.constrain();
    let clocks = reset_and_clock_control.cfgr.freeze(&mut flash.acr);
    let delay = Delay::new(core_periphs.SYST, clocks);

    // initialize user leds
    let mut gpioe = device_periphs.GPIOE.split(&mut reset_and_clock_control.ahb);
    let leds = Leds::new(
        gpioe.pe8,
        gpioe.pe9,
        gpioe.pe10,
        gpioe.pe11,
        gpioe.pe12,
        gpioe.pe13,
        gpioe.pe14,
        gpioe.pe15,
        &mut gpioe.moder,
        &mut gpioe.otyper,
    );

    (delay, leds.into_array())
}
```

I have not changed anything in `lib.rs` and I am following [the instructions](https://rust-embedded.github.io/discovery/05-led-roulette/index.html) from the book, along with [the source code](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/tree/8ea5d2ca9b597d5e070a41cfc672e3ecf4ed97b9/src/05-led-roulette).

Running the code results in the following errors when building for the target:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `aux5::prelude`
 --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:5:19
  |
5 | use aux5::{entry, prelude::*, Delay, Leds};
  |                   ^^^^^^^ could not find `prelude` in `aux5`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:9:48
  |
9 |     let (mut delay, mut leds): (Delay, Leds) = aux5::init();
  |                                -------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Leds`, found array of 8 elements
  |                                |
  |                                expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected tuple `(Delay, Leds)`
             found tuple `(Delay, [Switch<PEx<Output<PushPull>>, ActiveHigh>; 8])`

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `Leds`
  --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         leds[0].on();
   |         ^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `delay_ms` found for struct `Delay` in the current scope
  --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:15:15
   |
15 |         delay.delay_ms(half_period);
   |               ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Delay`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
5  | use aux5::DelayMs;
   |

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `Leds`
  --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         leds[0].off();
   |         ^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `delay_ms` found for struct `Delay` in the current scope
  --> src\05-led-roulette\src\main.rs:18:15
   |
18 |         delay.delay_ms(half_period);
   |               ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Delay`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
5  | use aux5::DelayMs;
   |

error: aborting due to 6 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0308, E0432, E0599, E0608.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `led-roulette`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following page, ["The Led and Delay abstractions"](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/blob/6a791e05483c7130856413bf9ab74d7db5b0daf8/src/05-led-roulette/the-led-and-delay-abstractions.md), it looks like this is the set of imports that you need.

```rust
use aux5::{entry, Delay, DelayMs, LedArray, OutputSwitch};
```

In the above abstraction, compared to your `main.rs`, note the:

- Addition of [`DelayMs`](https://docs.rs/stm32f3xx-hal/0.6.1/stm32f3xx_hal/prelude/trait._embedded_hal_blocking_delay_DelayMs.html) trait, making `.delay_ms()` available.
- Removal of a `prelude` as it is not being used.
- Change from [`Leds`](https://docs.rs/stm32f3-discovery/0.6.0/stm32f3_discovery/leds/struct.Leds.html) to the expected [`LedArray`](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/blob/6a791e05483c7130856413bf9ab74d7db5b0daf8/src/05-led-roulette/auxiliary/src/lib.rs#L20).

Also see:

- [Stack Overflow, "Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type)

Comment: Thank you so much. If i would have opened two more md files i  would have found it ‍♂️. Thanks a lot

Comment: @iam-ankit glad to have been of help. I've gone through the book as well and it's a tremendous amount of fun.

[If this answer solved your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), you can mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark.