# Method "span" not found for reference "&ExprPath" (from "syn" crate)

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a function-like macro in Rust. It should be used as follows:

```
service!(FooService, "/foo_service");
```

This macro call shall generate a struct `FooServiceClient` and an impl `FooServiceClient` with various methods.

I am using the `syn` + `quote` duo and here are some relevant bits of my code:

```rust
struct ServiceDefinition {
    pub service_name: String,
    pub scope: String,
    pub operations: Vec<Operation>,
}

impl Parse for ServiceDefinition {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let params = Punctuated::<Expr, Token![,]>::parse_terminated(&input)?;
        let service_name = {
            let expr = &params[0];
            match expr {
                Expr::Path(ref expr_path) => {
                    let leading_colon = expr_path.path.leading_colon;
                    if let Some(leading_colon) = leading_colon {
                        return Err(Error::new(expr_path.span(), "expected unscoped identifier"));
                    }
                    if expr_path.path.segments.len() != 1 {
                        return Err(Error::new(expr_path.span(), "expected unscoped identifier"));
                    }

                    expr_path.path.segments.first().unwrap().ident
                },
                _ => {
                    return Err(Error::new(expr.span(), "expected service name"));
                }
            }
        };

        Ok(ServiceDefinition {
            service_name: service_name.to_string(),
            scope: "/foo".to_string(),
            operations: vec![],
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is still at the early stages of work in progress, but when I try to compile it, this is the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `span` found for reference `&ExprPath` in the current scope
   --> service_commons/src/lib.rs:58:57
    |
58  |                         return Err(Error::new(expr_path.span(), "expected unscoped identifier"));
    |                                                         ^^^^ method not found in `&ExprPath`
    |
```

As far as I can see in the docs, the method `span` should be on these types, but it's obviously missing for some reason.

I am using `syn = {version = "1.0.70", features = ["full"]}` in my Cargo file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` comes from the [`Spanned`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.70/syn/spanned/trait.Spanned.html) trait, so it needs to be in scope:

```rust
use syn::spanned::Spanned;
```

See also:

- [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type)

Comment: Wow! In my (still) limited knowledge of Rust, I am not sure why that is. Isn't the trait impl published from the crate as is the struct itself? Your suggestion works, but I am just curious why `use`ing the trait is needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Victor see the linked answer.