# Why `use`-ing a trait with overlapping methods changes type inference result?

Tags: rust

I was practicing with interior mutability and ran into behavior I cannot explain. Consider the following code:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

let shared: Rc<RefCell<u8>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
let mut borrowed = shared.borrow_mut();
*borrowed += 1;
```

It compiles and `borrowed` type is inferred as `RefMut<u8>`.

However, if you add `use std::borrow::BorrowMut;`, the code does not compile:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `Rc<RefCell<u8>>`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     *borrowed += 1;
  |     ---------^^^^^
  |     |
  |     cannot use `+=` on type `Rc<RefCell<u8>>`
```

and `borrowed` type is inferred as `&mut Rc<RefCell<u8>>` (if I understand correctly).

I see that both `RefCell` struct and `BorrowMut` trait have `borrow_mut` method, but it's not clear to me how simply `use`-ing the trait can change what method the compiler chooses.

Likely I don't know some details how method resolution works in Rust compiler. Can anybody help to understand it and/or share pointers where such subtleties are explained?

Comment: cause https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut != https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.BorrowMut.html#tymethod.borrow_mut I give you that use the same name make it confuse

Comment: "I see that both RefCell struct and BorrowMut trait have borrow_mut method, but it's not clear to me how simply use-ing the trait can change what method the compiler chooses." you literally use the use statlement to opt-in using this trait and so... use the function from trait instead of the function on the structure. I don't understand what you don't understand. You import the trait in the scope and you are surprise the code now use the trait function ?!?

Comment: @Stargateur exactly, I'm very much surprised that simply importing stuff somehow changes name resolution behavior for the object that has nothing to do with this import. I'm new to Rust, so if this is how it works in this language, I'd really like to learn more about it. So far, I could not find formal explanation of why this happens.

Comment: I think I found the answer (tl;dr: yes, traits _must_ be in scope to be visible and thus considered by compiler): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type

Comment: sorry I didn't find any official doc that talk about that... for me it's an obvious behavior

Comment: @Stargateur thank you anyway as I figured how to adjust my searching and find the answer by reading your comments here

Comment: Also, [`BorrowMut` is implemented for `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-BorrowMut%3CT%3E) whereas reaching `RefCell::borrow_mut` requires that `shared` first be dereferenced, which has lower priority—so when `BorrowMut` is in scope, that's where you end up.  You can of course explicitly dereference to still get the original behaviour: `(&*shared).borrow_mut()` or `shared.deref().borrow_mut()` (the latter requires that `std::ops::Deref` be in scope).

Comment: @eggyal yeah I figured it out now, will still update my answer with your comment. What was missing from my head is knowledge about these prioritization rules which are not terribly intuitive on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for me, I'm not the only one who is confused by this inherent vs trait methods dispatching rules: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39232.

Discussion on the issue resulted into adding what I was looking for to [rust-lang reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) which basically lists the steps performed by compiler to figure out which method to call. To summarize, `Rc` type is looked at before `RefCell` due to auto-dereference rules.

---

EDIT #1: (from @eggyal)

Also, `BorrowMut` is implemented for `Rc` whereas reaching `RefCell::borrow_mut` requires that shared first be dereferenced, which has lower priority—so when `BorrowMut` is in scope, that's where you end up. You can of course explicitly dereference to still get the original behaviour: `(&*shared).borrow_mut()` or `shared.deref().borrow_mut()` (the latter requires that `std::ops::Deref` be in scope).