# no method named `read_to_string` found for struct `File` in the current scope

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read a file into a string, but i get a compiler error with the message "error[E0599]: no method named `read_to_string` found for struct `File` in the current scope"

Can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the offending code below:

```
impl Todo {
    fn new() -> Result<Todo, std::io::Error> {
        let mut content = String::new();

        std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open("todo.txt")?
            .read_to_string(&mut content)?
       
    }
}
```

Versions:
cargo: 1.56.0
rustc: 1.56.1
rustup: 1.24.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use [the trait method `read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string), you have to bring [`Read` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) into the scope.

```
use std::io::Read;
```

See also:

- [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type)