# Why aren't traits necessary in scope when they are not used in a method-like style?

Tags: rust, traits

When I implement a trait for a given struct, I can obviously only use it by bringing the trait into scope. For example:

```rust
// file1.rs
pub struct MyStruct {
  value: u64;
}

impl MyStruct {
  pub fn new(value: u64) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { value }
  }
}

impl BitOr<MyStruct> for MyStruct {
  type Output = Self;

  fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
    Self::new(self.value | rhs.value)
  }
}

// main.rs
use file1::MyStruct;

let t1 = MyStruct::new(10u64);
let t2 = MyStruct::new(15u64);
let t3 = t1.bitor(t2);  // This gives a compilation error unless std::ops::BitOr is in scope
```

The compiler has some useful warnings about this behaviour:

```
= help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
    |
1   | use std::ops::BitOr;
    |
```

However, if I replace `let t3 = t1.bitor(t2);` with `let t3 = t1 | t2;`, then the code compiles without errors even if `std::ops::BitOr` is not in scope. Why is that?

Comment: Operators are always in scope because they're built into the language syntax and are unambiguous (always refer to `std::ops::Trait`). Multiple traits can define the same method, so a method call can be ambiguous. Because there's no reason to have the trait in scope if you can always use the operator and including the trait in scope could introduce ambiguities, it makes sense to not include in the standard prelude.

Comment: @PitaJ sounds like an answer to me

Comment: Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type