# Rust not finding method of trait struct because of lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, struct, traits

I was trying to do simple struct with few traits following examples on the internet an came across the following problem.

```
//My struct in framebuffer.rs
pub struct HighLevelFrameBuffer<'a> {
    pub fbinfo: FrameBufferInfo,
    pub fbdata: &'a mut [u8],
    pub pixel_bytesize: u8,
    pub color: FrameBufferColor,
}
//Trait and implementation
trait WriteLine {
    fn write_line(&self, line: usize, color: FrameBufferColor);
}
impl<'a> WriteLine for HighLevelFrameBuffer<'a> {

    fn write_line(&self, line: usize, color: FrameBufferColor) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

When I try to call this from my main function as follows from main.rs:

```
mod framebuffer;
pub use framebuffer::HighLevelFrameBuffer;
pub use framebuffer::FrameBufferColor;

let hlfb = HighLevelFrameBuffer{
    fbinfo: something,
    fbdata: data_location,
    pixel_bytesize: 0,
    color:  FrameBufferColor {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}
};
hlfb.write_line(100, FrameBufferColor{r: 0xFF, g: 0xFF, b: 0xFF});
```

Compiler tells me that there is no implementation of write_line for HighLevelFrameBuffer struct:

```
hlfb.write_line(100, FrameBufferColor{r: 0xFF, g: 0xFF, b: 0xFF});
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `HighLevelFrameBuffer<'_>` 
pub struct HighLevelFrameBuffer<'a> {
   | ----------------------------------- method `write_line` not found for this struct
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Compiles fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b3f9202d0c2c936f80fd724898179a3 (Playground)

Comment: @isaactfa the struct definition and trait are in a separate file from where I try to use them, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a couple reasons for this:

1. Did you make a typo when typing  `write_line`?
2. Is `WriteLine` defined in a different file from where you're calling `hlfb.write_line`? If it is, then have you added a `use` statement to import `WriteLine`?

It's hard to be more specific without more details.

Comment: Yes, the definition of WriteLine is in a different file than where I want to call it from. I have added the HighLevelFrameBuffer import with `mod framebuffer;` and 
`pub use framebuffer::HighLevelFrameBuffer;` this isn't enough to import the related trait?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer It's not enough, you have to import the trait itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type