# How to use multipart/form-data with hyper server and multer in Rust?

Tags: rust, stream, traits, multer, hyper

Currently I am trying to make file uploads to my web server - built on top of hyper - work. For that a request with multipart/form-data is sent to it.

Since hyper is using struct `Incoming` on the 1.0.0-rc.4 version and `multer::Multipart` is requiring the stream to implement the trait `futures_core::stream::Stream` I am unable to make this work.
If I understand it correctly, somehow I need to implement a wrapper struct but since the `poll_frame` method of `Incoming` is private, I am not able to call it from outside.

So yea, I am out of ideas and hope you can help me with that.

Code trying to use `Multipart`:

```
pub async fn handle_request(
    &self,
    mut req: Request,
) -> Result<hyper::Response<Full<Bytes>>, Infallible> {
    // req.collect_body().await; // * The way I use it for normal API requests

    let stream = req.body_stream_mut();
    let mut multipart = Multipart::new(stream, "EvaluatedBoundary"); // <-- The important part that causes the error "the trait bound `hyper::body::Incoming: futures_core::stream::Stream` is not satisfied ..."

    let mut res = view_function(&req).await; // * Maybe I change this to &mut so that the view_function can decide if it want to collect the body or use the stream in another way like Multipart

    res
}
```

Code of my `Request` implementation:

```
impl Request {
    pub fn from(hyper_req: hyper::Request<hyper::body::Incoming>) -> Self {
        let (req, body) = hyper_req.into_parts();
        Request {
            body: Bytes::new(),
            body_stream: body,
            uri: req.uri,
        }
    }

    pub async fn collect_body(&mut self) -> &hyper::body::Bytes {
        let collected_body = self
            .body_stream_mut()
            .collect()
            .await
            .ok()
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .to_bytes();

        self.body = collected_body;

        &self.body
    }

    pub fn body_stream_mut(&mut self) -> &mut hyper::body::Incoming {
        &mut self.body_stream
    }
}
```

Comment: `poll_frame` is implemented as part of the `Body` trait, it's not private.

Comment: Yes it is but not as public. Here is the part of the implementation in incoming.rs. `impl Body for Incoming {
    type Data = Bytes;
    type Error = crate::Error;

    fn poll_frame(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Result<Frame<Self::Data>, Self::Error>>> {...}}`

Comment: There is no "not as public" between crates either it is public, that means you can call it or it isn't. In this case it's public.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, a function must be implemented with `pub fn poll_frame` to call it from outside. Because in this case it isn't, I am unable to call it. Even if I try it, I get the error "no method named `poll_frame` found for struct `hyper::body::Incoming` in the current scope
method not found in `hyper::body::Incoming`"

Comment: Sorry, I now see the point. I tried calling it on the instance of Incoming, not the struct itself. I will try to make it work with this

Comment: You're wrong, a function doesn't need to be declared `pub fn …` to be able to use it if the trait has been declared as `pub trait …` but the trait has to be in scope. You might be interested in reading up this Q/A: [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273816/why-do-i-need-to-import-a-trait-to-use-the-methods-it-defines-for-a-type)